# Common format to represent a data mapping allowing duplicated column/key names

Tags: php, duplicates, export-to-csv, data-representation

**Context:**
I actually have an extracting task in **PHP** which executes a **SQL** query and generates a **CSV** file. The CSV columns names are based on the query column names.
The CSV must contain a lot of columns and **some column names appear multiple times** (2 or 3 times). The team processing this extract need all of the columns because the value can change from a duplicate column to an other, and the order is important.

**From SQL to CSV:**
I can set aliases in the SQL query `SELECT` statement with duplicated names:

```sql
SELECT
    col_a AS 'duplicate',
    col_b AS 'some_col',
    '' AS 'duplicate',
    col_c AS 'other_col',
...
```

The query is executed with **PDO** and fetched with a classic `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` which returns an associative array. As the keys of an array are unique, I lose the duplicated columns:

```php
[
    'duplicate' => 'something',
    'some_col'  => 'value',
    'other_col' => 'other value'
    ...
]
```

**Failing solutions:**
Using the `PDO::FETCH_NAMED` fetch mode would not work because I would lose the order of the columns, requiring much more work to make it work in a reusable way (the task is a generic SQL/CSV extract).

I can rename the aliases in the `SELECT` clause to be unique but then I wouldn't be able to use the column names for the CSV.
**Except if I have a mapping of the SQL columns to the CSV columns.**

I thought about a format like JSON but this won't work as JSON data *should not* contain duplicated keys, and I would lose them while reading them in PHP anyway:

```json
{
    "CSV_COL": "SQL_COL",
    "OTHER_CSV": "OTHER_SQL",
    "CSV_COL": "something_else"
}
```

Is there a simple format that could allow for duplicate column/key names that PHP would not delete while reading it ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a custom format. This is not the ideal solution as I would prefer a more standard one but it works. Here are the details:

#### Custom format

First, a form field accepts text input like the following:

```
csv_column:sql_column

Name of CSV column   :   "some string"
 csv_column :
```

Rules of the format:

- each line maps a **CSV column** to a **SQL column / value**
- blank lines are ignored but are fine
- **CSV** columns are separated from **SQL** columns with a `:`
- you can add as many whitespaces as you want around column names
- you can define a default string value for the **SQL** side by enclosing the value with `'` or `"`
- if a **CSV** column must be empty, the **SQL** part is optional

#### Format parsing

Then I wrote a function which will transform this string into a multidimensionnal array:

```php
/**
 * Parse CSV/SQL column mapping.
 * @param string $textMapping column mapping in text format
 * @return string[][]|null each array has a "CSV" & "SQL" key with corresponding column/value and a "type" key to
 *                         differentiate SQL columns from SQL values
 */
function getColumnMapping(string $textMapping): ?array
{
    // No mapping
    if (trim($textMapping) === '') {
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * RegEx explanation:
     *      \h*(.*\S)   optional whitepaces following by a CSV column name
     *                  (anything but does not end with whitespace)
     *      \h*:\h*     a colon optionally surrounded by whitespaces
     *      ([^\v]*)\h* an optional SQL column/value, optionally followed by whitespaces
     *                  (anything but line breaks)
     *      (?:\R|$)    a line break or the end of the string
     *
     * CSV parts are at index 1 and SQL parts are at index 2
     */
    preg_match_all('~\h*(.*\S)\h*:\h*([^\v]*)\h*(?:\R|$)~', $textMapping, $matches);

    // No mapping found
    if ([] === $matches[0]) {
        return null;
    }

    $mapping = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
        $mappingItem = [
            'CSV' => $matches[1][$i],
            'SQL' => $matches[2][$i],
            'type' => 'column',
        ];

        if ('' === $mappingItem['SQL']) {
            // Empty: empty value
            $mappingItem['type'] = 'value';
        } elseif (1 === preg_match('~^(\'|")(.*)\1$~', $mappingItem['SQL'], $match)) {
            // Enclosed by quotes: string value
            $mappingItem['SQL'] = $match[2];
            $mappingItem['type'] = 'value';
        }

        $mapping[] = $mappingItem;
    }

    return $mapping;
}
```

The previous example would result in the following array:

```php
[
    [
        'CSV'  => 'csv_column',
        'SQL'  => 'sql_column',
        'type' => 'column',
    ],
    [
        'CSV'  => 'Name of CSV column',
        'SQL'  => 'some string',
        'type' => 'value',
    ],
    [
        'CSV'  => 'csv_column',
        'SQL'  => '',
        'type' => 'value',
    ],
]
```

#### Building the CSV file

Finally, after executing the SQL query, each result is passed to a function to build the data row:

```php
/**
 * Build a CSV data line based on a column mapping
 * @param array $resultRow SQL result row
 * @param array $mapping CSV/SQL column mapping
 * @return array formatted data
 */
function buildRowFromColumnMapping(array $resultRow, array $mapping): array
{
    $row = [];

    foreach ($mapping as $mappingItem) {
        if ($mappingItem['type'] === 'value') {
            $row[] = $mappingItem['SQL'];
        } elseif (false === array_key_exists($mappingItem['SQL'], $resultRow)) {
            throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Column "%s" not found.', $mappingItem['SQL']));
        } else {
            $row[] = $resultRow[$mappingItem['SQL']];
        }
    }

    return $row;
}
```

The result is a unidimensionnal array you can send to anything you want ([fputcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv), specific lib, ...).